# Can we sync GA4 data of past 6 months in google big-query ? If yes how we can?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have linked google analytic with big-query. After some hours I only got data of the past 1 day. What should I do since the data of the past 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the wizard for [Backfilling](https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-backfill-google-analytics-data-in-bigquery/). Essentially you setup a scheduling process that will ad your data from past. Some limitations apply, so don't expect this will be a full backfilling.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no backfill - Unlike UA, GA4 does not offer any history or 'backfill' when activating the BigQuery export.

You will need to create summary tables using the same dimensions and metrics in both data sources, then blend those together into a report table.

Your workflow will look something like this, only the output is to back to BigQuery instead of Looker Studio:
[image: GA4 API to GA4 BigQuery data flow]

Full details on how to do this found here: https://analyticscanvas.com/blending-data-between-ua-ga4-and-ga4-bigquery/#blending-between-ga4-API-and-ga4-bigquery